# JS - Laravel Mix/NPM.js: variable twemoji.parse not found/undefined

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, laravel-mix, twemoji

Good day all,

With Laravel Mix I'm trying to install Twemoji — among other modules — using Node.

I'm getting console errors, indicating that the **dependencies aren't loaded correctly**.

For instance: **`TypeError: t.parse is not a function. (In 't.parse(document.body)', 't.parse' is undefined)`**

**Twemoji was installed as follows:**

1. Run the shell command `npm install twemoji`
2. Add `require('twemoji');` to my JS file that's going to be mixed by Laravel
3. Run Laravel Mix (`npm run production -- --watch`)

Another module, Datepicker, is running just fine. It was imported the same way and is imported through `require('@chenfengyuan/datepicker');` in the same file.

**My package.json:**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^5.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.4",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "vue": "^2.5.7"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@chenfengyuan/datepicker": "^1.0.0",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.2",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1",
        "signature_pad": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
        "twemoji": "^11.0.1"
    }
}
```

Any help to get Twemoji working properly is much appreciated. Thank you in advance, and have a good evening.

Yours,
Thierry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed `require('twemoji');` to `var twemoji = require('twemoji/2/twemoji.npm.js');`

That's that. But my opinion is that `require('twemoji');` should work as well.